# PHP MySQL User Id

Tags: php, mysql

This code is supposed to get the user id from my database but it returns this : Resource id #6

So how would I code this to make it return the user id?Here is  my code so far and I know that mysql_query is becoming outdated:

```
<?php
include("login_check.php");
include("dbconnect.php");
mysql_select_db("maxgee_close2");
$username = $_COOKIE['maxgee_me_user']; 
$user_id = mysql_query("select user_id from users where username = '$username'");
echo "$user_id";
?>
```

Comment: (And) - Is the $_COOKIE actually set? It must be sent by setcookie / setrawcookie.

Comment: @davidkonrad Yes it is already set

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or 
  die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("maxgee_close2");
$result = mysql_query("select user_id from users where username = '$username'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['user_id'];    
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

[From the `mysql_query()` documentation:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.
>
> ...
>
> The returned result resource should be passed to mysql_fetch_array(),
>   and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the
>   returned data.

**tl;dr** mysql_query returns a resource that you have to pass to another function such as mysql_fetch_array(). The ressource itself doesn't contain your rows.

Answer (score 2):

That code it's not supposed to return the ID, but a resource! You then need to access the data in that resource,
Read here: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlfetcharray.php (or maybe the official PHP docs)